# How to sort data by column excluding the first row

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I need to sort a worksheet by the 11th column. This code works but includes the column header so that it moves down the worksheet.

I have already tried the below code

```
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
var startCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
var endCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row, 12];

Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell];
range.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
range.Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;

Excel.Range fullDataRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
fullDataRange.Sort(fullDataRange.Columns[11], 
Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);

excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(txtOutputFolder.Text + "\\" + 
filestart + " Instructions" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" dd.MM") + ".xlsx");
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.sort?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Sort_System_Object_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortOrder_System_Object_System_Object_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortOrder_System_Object_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortOrder_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlYesNoGuess_System_Object_System_Object_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortOrientation_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortMethod_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortDataOption_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortDataOption_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlSortDataOption_) documentation you will see that you can specify if the sort range has a header. Just add a named parameter to you sort command :

```
fullDataRange.Sort(fullDataRange.Columns[11], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Header:xlYes);
```

and the first row will be ignored when sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the range you want:

```
 worksheet.Range("A1:H8")
```

Comment: Where do I add this in exactly?

Comment: Excel.Range fullDataRange = worksheet.Range("A2:"+endCell.toString())

Comment: Error on UsedRange:
Non-invoacable member '_Worksheet.UsedRange' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: did you use worksheet.Range instead of worksheet usedrange?